# Extract random effect variances from lme4 mer model object

Tags: r, random, effects, lme4

I have a mer object that has fixed and random effects.  How do I extract the variance estimates for the random effects?  Here is a simplified version of my question.

```
study <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (1|Subject), data = sleepstudy)
study
```

This gives a long output - not too long in this case.  Anyway, how do I explicitly select the

```
Random effects:
Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
Subject  (Intercept) 1378.18  37.124  
Residual              960.46  30.991
```

part of the output?  I want the values themselves.

I have taken long looks at

```
str(study)
```

and there's nothing there!  Also checked any extractor functions in the lme4 package to no avail.  Please help!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`lmer` returns an S4 object, so this should work:

```
remat <- summary(study)@REmat
print(remat, quote=FALSE)
```

Which prints:

```
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 Subject  (Intercept) 1378.18  37.124  
 Residual              960.46  30.991
```

...In general, you can look at the source of the `print` and `summary` methods for "mer" objects:

```
class(study) # mer
selectMethod("print", "mer")
selectMethod("summary", "mer")
```

Comment: If you want the values then VarCorr() is much more efficient. Have a look at the post of Ben Bolker

Comment: this is somewhat out of date now (although the original question does refer to "mer objects", which are by definition associated with pre-1.0 `lme4` -- the class is now called `merMod`.

Answer (score 90):

Some of the other answers are workable, but I claim that the best answer is to use the accessor method that is designed for this -- `VarCorr` (this is the same as in `lme4`'s predecessor, the `nlme` package).

**UPDATE** in recent versions of `lme4` (version 1.1-7, but everything below is probably applicable to versions >= 1.0), `VarCorr` is more flexible than before, and should do everything you want without ever resorting to fishing around inside the fitted model object.

```
library(lme4)
study <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (1|Subject), data = sleepstudy)
VarCorr(study)
##  Groups   Name        Std.Dev.
##  Subject  (Intercept) 37.124  
##  Residual             30.991
```

By default `VarCorr()` prints standard deviations, but you can get variances instead if you prefer:

```
print(VarCorr(study),comp="Variance")
##  Groups   Name        Variance
##  Subject  (Intercept) 1378.18 
##  Residual              960.46
```

(`comp=c("Variance","Std.Dev.")` will print both).

For more flexibility, you can use the `as.data.frame` method to convert the `VarCorr` object, which gives the grouping variable, effect variable(s), and the variance/covariance or standard deviation/correlations:

```
as.data.frame(VarCorr(study))
##        grp        var1 var2      vcov    sdcor
## 1  Subject (Intercept) <NA> 1378.1785 37.12383
## 2 Residual        <NA> <NA>  960.4566 30.99123
```

Finally, the raw form of the `VarCorr` object (which you probably shouldn't mess with you if you don't have to) is a list of variance-covariance matrices with additional (redundant) information encoding the standard deviations and correlations, as well as attributes (`"sc"`) giving the residual standard deviation and specifying whether the model has an estimated scale parameter (`"useSc"`).

```
unclass(VarCorr(fm1))
## $Subject
##             (Intercept)      Days
## (Intercept)  612.089748  9.604335
## Days           9.604335 35.071662
## attr(,"stddev")
## (Intercept)        Days 
##   24.740448    5.922133 
## attr(,"correlation")
##             (Intercept)       Days
## (Intercept)  1.00000000 0.06555134
## Days         0.06555134 1.00000000
## 
## attr(,"sc")
## [1] 25.59182
## attr(,"useSc")
## [1] TRUE
##
```

Comment: VarCorr seems only to provide the std deviations not the variance estimates which is what in general people would like to report right?

Comment: (1) it's pretty easy to square the standard deviations; (2) `print(VarCorr(fitted_model),comp="Variance")` or `as.data.frame(VarCorr(fitted_model))` will easily retrieve the variances; (3) reporting variances vs standard deviations is context dependent -- I generally prefer variances if trying to think about var decomposition/proportion explained and std devs if trying to compare to the magnitude of fixed effects

Answer (score 5):

```
> attributes(summary(study))$REmat
 Groups     Name          Variance  Std.Dev.
 "Subject"  "(Intercept)" "1378.18" "37.124"
 "Residual" ""            " 960.46" "30.991"
```

Comment: I might be wrong, by there looks to be no `REmat` in `attributes(summary(study))` anymore

Answer (score 2):

This package is useful for things like this (https://easystats.github.io/insight/reference/index.html)

```
library("insight")

get_variance_random(study) #Where study is your fit mixed model
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer is heavily based on that on @Ben Bolker's, but if people are new to this and want the values themselves, instead of just a printout of the values (as OP seems to have wanted), then you can extract the values as follows:

Convert the `VarCorr` object to a data frame.

```
re_dat = as.data.frame(VarCorr(study))
```

Then access each individual value:

```
int_vcov = re_dat[1,'vcov']
resid_vcov = re_dat[2,'vcov']
```

With this method (specifying rows and columns in the date frame you created) you can access whichever values you'd like.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is

```
sum <- summary (study)
var <- data.frame (sum$varcor)
```

Answer (score -9):

Try

```
attributes(study)
```

As an example:

```
> women
   height weight
1      58    115
2      59    117
3      60    120
4      61    123
5      62    126
6      63    129
7      64    132
8      65    135
9      66    139
10     67    142
11     68    146
12     69    150
13     70    154
14     71    159
15     72    164

> lm1 <- lm(height ~ weight, data=women)
> attributes(lm1)
$names
 [1] "coefficients"  "residuals"     "effects"       "rank"         
 [5] "fitted.values" "assign"        "qr"            "df.residual"  
 [9] "xlevels"       "call"          "terms"         "model"        

$class
[1] "lm"

> lm1$coefficients
(Intercept)      weight 
 25.7234557   0.2872492 

> lm1$coefficients[[1]]

[1] 25.72346


> lm1$coefficients[[2]]

[1] 0.2872492
```

The end.

Comment: Err, your code uses `lm()`,  the questions was about `lmer()` which is *not* the same thing.