# How to get coefficients and their confidence intervals in mixed effects models?

Tags: r, lme4, random-effects, mixed-models

In `lm` and `glm` models, I use functions `coef` and `confint` to achieve the goal:

```
m = lm(resp ~ 0 + var1 + var1:var2) # var1 categorical, var2 continuous
coef(m)
confint(m)
```

Now I added random effect to the model - used mixed effects models using `lmer` function from lme4 package. But then, functions `coef` and `confint` do not work any more for me!

```
> mix1 = lmer(resp ~ 0 + var1 + var1:var2 + (1|var3)) 
                                      # var1, var3 categorical, var2 continuous
> coef(mix1)
Error in coef(mix1) : unable to align random and fixed effects
> confint(mix1)
Error: $ operator not defined for this S4 class
```

I tried to google and use docs but with no result. Please point me in the right direction.

EDIT: I was also thinking whether this question fits more to https://stats.stackexchange.com/ but I consider it more technical than statistical, so I concluded it fits best here (SO)... what do you think?

Comment: To get you started until someone like @BenBolker shows up (an expert): `?lmer` lists methods `fixef` and `ranef` in addition to `coef`. Since your error says it's having trouble combining the two, the issue is likely that your model specification is somehow "unusual".

Comment: Thanks @joran. My model spec is maybe unusual in omitting the intercept - I want to do this, because otherwise the coefficients are nonsense. `var1` is categorical and I want "group specific intercepts" for each its category. If I allow the intercept (remove `0 + ` from formula), `coef` runs but doesn't give what I expect. `fixef` works great, thanks! However the `confint` doesn't work at all.

Comment: I would extract the data you need directly from the S4 object -- see this post's answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8526681/extract-random-effect-variances-from-lme4-mer-model-object

Comment: Thanks @baha-kev, but are you sure the confidence intervals are in this object? I don't think so...

Comment: Not directly, but you would just need to multiply the standard error by +/- 1.96 and add it to the coefficient estimates for a 95% confidence interval, for example.  The S4 object has the standard errors and the coefficient estimates.

Comment: I am fixing the bug(let)? in `coef` in the r-forge versions of lme4 (lme4.0, the currently stable branch which corresponds to CRAN-lme4), and lme4, the development branch). `confint` is a bigger can of worms, as has been discussed, although the development branch of lme4 can calculate profile confidence intervals ...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm going to add a bit here.  If `m` is a fitted `(g)lmer` model (most of these work for `lme` too):

- `fixef(m)` is the canonical way to extract coefficients from mixed models (this convention began with `nlme` and has carried over to `lme4`)
- you can get the full coefficient table with `coef(summary(m))`; if you have loaded `lmerTest` before fitting the model, or convert the model after fitting (and then loading `lmerTest`) via `coef(summary(as(m,"lmerModLmerTest")))`, then the coefficient table will include p-values. (The coefficient table is a matrix; you can extract the columns via e.g. `ctab[,"Estimate"]`, `ctab[,"Pr(>|t|)"]`, or convert the matrix to a data frame and use `$`-indexing.)
- As stated above you can get *likelihood profile* confidence intervals via `confint(m)`; these may be computationally intensive. If you use `confint(m, method="Wald")` you'll get the standard +/- 1.96SE confidence intervals. (`lme` uses `intervals(m)` instead of `confint()`.)

If you prefer to use `broom.mixed`:

- `tidy(m,effects="fixed")` gives you a table with estimates, standard errors, etc.
- `tidy(as(m,"merModLmerTest"), effects="fixed")` (or fitting with `lmerTest` in the first place) includes p-values
- adding `conf.int=TRUE` gives (Wald) CIs
- adding `conf.method="profile"` (along with `conf.int=TRUE`) gives likelihood profile CIs

You can also get confidence intervals by parametric bootstrap (`method="boot"`), which is considerably slower but more accurate in some circumstances.

Comment: Hi Ben, thanks! I'm a bit confused, what does the standalone dot `.` mean? If it's just a model var name, why not use e.g. `m`? :-)

Comment: I could use `m`.  Sometimes I use `.` as a placeholder.

Answer (score 19):

Not sure when it was added, but now confint() is implemented in lme4.
For example the following example works:

```
library(lme4)
m = lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days | Subject), sleepstudy)
confint(m)
```

Answer (score 15):

There are two packages, [lmerTest](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lmerTest//lmerTest.pdf) and [emmeans](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lsmeans/lsmeans.pdf), that can calculate 95% confidence limits for `lmer` and `glmer` output. Maybe you can look into those? And [coefplot2](http://r-forge.r-project.org/projects/coefplot2), I think can do it too (though as Ben points out below, in a not so sophisticated way, from the standard errors on the Wald statistics, as opposed to Kenward-Roger and/or Satterthwaite df approximations used in `lmerTest` and `emmeans`)...

Comment: `coefplot2` does it very naively, by computing 1.96 times the Wald standard errors -- it doesn't address the very significant issues of finite-size corrections to the CIs

Comment: Check also this post http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/117641/how-trustworthy-are-the-confidence-intervals-for-lmer-objects-through-effects-pa for a more detailed answer

Comment: `lmerTest` is now nicely described in JoSS https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v082i13

Comment: Note that many of these comments are now quite outdated. Using `emmeans` or `lmerTest` is the way to go, and there are plotting methods now.

Answer (score 9):

Assuming a normal approximation for the fixed effects (which confint would also have done), we can  obtain 95% confidence intervals by

estimate + 1.96*standard error.

The following does not apply to the variance components/random effects.

```
library("lme4")
mylm <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days|Subject),  data =sleepstudy)

# standard error of coefficient

days_se <- sqrt(diag(vcov(mylm)))[2]

# estimated coefficient

days_coef <- fixef(mylm)[2]

upperCI <-  days_coef + 1.96*days_se
lowerCI <-  days_coef  - 1.96*days_se
```

Comment: Hi julieth, nice idea, however [there is a difference between the real confidence intervals (computed by confint) and these ...](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/29981/5509). Maybe the t-distribution would give the same result as confint (not sure about this though), but in this case I don't know the df which should be used.

Comment: In other words, this is the reason why I prefer to use functions like `confint` etc. to do all this for me... (especially if I'm not sure about the normal distribution of coefficients).

Comment: The t-distribution is asymptotically normal and the degrees of freedom for the error term in many multi-level designs is so high that the error distribution is normal at that point.  Therefore, if you have a design with lots of degrees of freedom this is a perfectly reasonable confidence interval estimate.

Answer (score 8):

I suggest that you use good old lme (in package nlme). It has confint, and if you need confint of contrasts, there is a series of choices (estimable in gmodels, contrast in contrasts, glht in multcomp).

Why p-values and confint are absent in lmer: see http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/R/Rhelp02a/archive/76742.html .

Comment: Thanks Dieter, I will try the older package. The absence of p-value  - and possibility to tell significance right away - also alarmed me! Doesn't make any sense to me, if I will be able to get confidence interval then I will simply look whether it contains zero - and have the significance anyway! Regards,

Comment: I forget to mention that confint(glht... from package multcomp give  asymptotic confidence intervals for lmer. Douglas Bates caveats still apply, but his bold move to leave the p-value out of lmer/gaussian certainly has stirred the soup.

Comment: Dieter, what do you mean with "confint(glht" ? There's no confint function in multcomp package...

Comment: Dieter, I tried the old package lme, nice, it has p-values. But my main concern is to get the confidence interval of fixed effect coefficients. How do I do that? confint returns some big matrix, glht seems too complicated..

Comment: There is confint.glht. See examples and http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/multcomp/vignettes/multcomp-examples.pdf

Comment: using `intervals(mix1)`  will you give you asymptotic confidence intervals as in @julieth's answer below; `intervals(mix1)$fixed` extracts the fixed-effect intervals.  These are based on the normal approximation, not the t distribution or anything more exotic ...

Comment: You are right for the default table; I was thinking of non-default contrast.

Answer (score 1):

To find the coefficient, you can simply use the summary function of lme4

```
m = lm(resp ~ 0 + var1 + var1:var2) # var1 categorical, var2 continuous
m_summary <- summary(m)
```

to have all coefficients :

```
m_summary$coefficient
```

If you want the confidence interval, multiply the standart error by 1.96:

```
CI <- m_summary$coefficient[,"Std. Error"]*1.96
print(CI)
```

Comment: here the 1.96 factor is for 95% confidence interval of course

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest `tab_model()` function from `sjPlot` package as alternative. Clean and readable output ready for markdown. Reference [here](https://strengejacke.github.io/sjPlot/reference/tab_model.html) and examples [here](https://strengejacke.github.io/sjPlot/articles/tab_model_estimates.html).

For those more visually inclined `plot_model()` from the same package might come handy too.

Alternative solution is via `parameters` [package](https://github.com/easystats/parameters) using `model_parameters()` [function](https://easystats.github.io/parameters/articles/model_parameters.html).

Comment: or `broom.mixed::tidy()`

Comment: @Ben Bolker's should be the top rated answer IMO :)