# Generalized Linear Mixed Model: Using estimable() with glmer() to generate linear combination of coefficients

Tags: r, logistic-regression, binomial-coefficients

I have a generalized linear mixed model with a three way interaction, a nested random variable, and a binomial response variable :

```
modelB15=glmer(cbind(resistant, (total-resistant) )~
               time*inoc_source*inoc_resistance+
               (1|block/plot),
               family = binomial,
               data = B15)
```

the corresponding matrix to generate linear combinations of coefficients (a contrast matrix) is:

```
time1_sourceHY_mix      = c(1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
time2_sourceHY_mix      = c(1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
time1_sourceNV_mix      = c(1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
time1_sourceHY_negative = c(1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
time1_sourceHY_positive = c(1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
time1_sourceNV_negative = c(1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0)
time1_sourceNV_positive = c(1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0)
time2_sourceNV_mix      = c(1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0)
time2_sourceHY_negative = c(1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0)
time2_sourceHY_positive = c(1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0)
time2_sourceNV_negative = c(1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0)
time2_sourceNV_positive = c(1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1)
```

I then can pull up the vectors to test different hypotheses, such as "is time 1 different from time 2"?

```
time_HYpositive = time2_sourceHY_negative-time1_sourceHY_positive
time_HYnegative = time2_sourceHY_negative-time1_sourceHY_negative
time_HYmix      = time2_sourceHY_mix-time1_sourceHY_mix
time_NVpositive = time2_sourceNV_negative-time1_sourceNV_positive
time_NVnegative = time2_sourceNV_negative-time1_sourceNV_negative
time_NVmix      = time2_sourceNV_mix-time1_sourceNV_mix

timeDiff=rbind(time_HYpositive, time_HYnegative, time_HYmix,
 time_NVpositive,time_NVnegative,time_NVmix)
```

I want to use estimable() in library(gmodels) to make different comparisons between means for each coefficient or combination of coefficients:

```
estimable(modelB15, timeDiff, conf.int=.991)
```

but I get the following error message:

```
Error in FUN(newX[, i], ...) : 'param' has no names and does not match number of coefficients of model. Unable to construct coefficient vector
```

estimable() works great with a glm, but a) how can it be modified to work with lmer() b) if estimable won't work with a GLMM, what other functions could accomplish the same task?

I have tried `glmmPQL()`, it doesn't work either.

The author in [this page](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-mixed-models/2007q4/000429.html) is trying to accomplish a similar thing.

[This page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11072544/how-to-get-coefficients-and-their-confidence-intervals-in-mixed-effects-models) was a bit helpful.

Answer (score 0):

`estimable()` will not work with `glmer()`

However, the `lsmeans()` package is compatible with generalized linear mixed models and can generate LS means via pairwise comparisons. This gives the user the ability to compare combinations of coefficients, without generating a messy matrix.

[[Rethinking the analysis of non-normal data in plant and soil science]](https://dl.sciencesocieties.org/publications/aj/pdfs/107/2/811) by Walter W. Stroup has an excellent description and supplementary documents contain useful example R code