# Extract a column from lme4 summary in R

Tags: r, dataframe, extract, lme4, nlme

I was wondering what is the most efficient way to extract (not print like [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8526681/extract-random-effect-variances-from-lme4-mer-model-object)) only the `Std.Dev.` column from the `vc` object below as a vector?

```
library(lme4)
library(nlme)

data(Orthodont, package = "nlme")
fm1 <- lmer(distance ~ age + (age|Subject), data = Orthodont)

vc <- VarCorr(fm1) ## extract only the `Std.Dev.` column as a vector
```

Comment: If you check `getAnywhere("as.data.frame.VarCorr.merMod")`, it is doing the extraction of the components to create the data.frame `vcov <- c(diag(v), v[lt.v <- lower.tri(v, diag = FALSE)]);sdcor <- c(attr(v, "stddev"), attr(v, "correlation")[lt.v])`

Comment: It is internally doing the same thing `r <- rbind(r, data.frame(grp = "Residual", var1 = NA, 
            var2 = NA, vcov = ss^2, sdcor = ss)` in the code.  So, it may be efficient to extract the sd and do the `^` instead of going over the as.data.frame and do all the steps which may not be needed for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `str`ucture of 'vc' suggests it is a `list` with single element 'Subject' and the 'stddev' is an attribute

```
str(vc)
#List of 1
# $ Subject: num [1:2, 1:2] 6.3334 -0.3929 -0.3929 0.0569
#  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
#  .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "(Intercept)" "age"
#  .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "(Intercept)" "age"
#  ..- attr(*, "stddev")= Named num [1:2] 2.517 0.239  ####
```

So, extract the attribute directly

```
attr(vc$Subject, "stddev")
```

and the residual standard deviation is an outside attribute

```
attr(vc, "sc")
#[1] 1.297364
```

---

If we combine them with `c`, we get a single `vector`

```
c(attr(vc$Subject, "stddev"), attr(vc, "sc"))
#   (Intercept)         age             
#  2.5166317   0.2385853   1.2973640
```

Wrap with `as.numeric/as.vector` to remove the names as it is a `named` vector

Or use `attributes`

```
c(attributes(vc)$sc, attributes(vc$Subject)$stddev)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the three elements in the column, you can use:

```
as.numeric(c(attr(vc[[1]], "stddev"), attr(vc, "sc")))
```